# specify classifier and type in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, log4j2

I need to add a dependency ([test-jar](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/dependencies.html), from log4j), but I don't know what is the correct syntax in gradle to include it in the *compile("..")* config step.

I need to specify the *classifier* and the *type*, but in the compile step I can only specify :group :name :version.

What is the correct syntax?

(I am using gradle 2.7)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I eventually found the way.

```
compile(group:name:version:classifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro already answered his question, but I would like to give reference to documentation.

Correct way of using *dependencyNotation* is:

```
For Gradle:
configurationName "group:name:version:classifier@extension"

For Kotlin:
configurationName("group:name:version:classifier@extension")
```

You can find more info about it in [Gradle Dependency Handler documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html#N16E3D).